# Is it possible to bind path variable and request param into a single object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

I'm creating an endpoint with path variable and request params.
How do I combine both path variable and request params into a single object? I'm using springboot 2 with java 8

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/schedules")
public class SchedulesController {

    @GetMapping("/{area}/{subarea}")
    public MyObject getFlight(@PathVariable("area") String area, @PathVariable("subarea") String subarea,
                           MyModel model) {

        ...
        return new MyObject();
    }
}

@Data
public class MyModel {
    LocalDate datestamp,
    String leadName,
    String viceLeadName
}
```

I've looked at the spring documentation and I can't seems to find how to combine PathVariable into MyModel.

Here is my controller without the object.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/schedules")
public class SchedulesController {

    @GetMapping("/{area}/{subarea}")
    public MyObject getFlight(@PathVariable("area") String area, @PathVariable("subarea") String subarea,
                            @RequestParam(value = "datestamp", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate datestamp,
                            @RequestParam(value = "leadName", required = false) String leadName,
                            @RequestParam(value = "viceLeadName", required = false) String viceLeadName) {

        ...
        return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the following? Where the path variables and request params are in MyModel object?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/schedules")
public class SchedulesController {

    @GetMapping("/{area}/{subarea}")
    public MyObject getFlight(MyModel model) {

        ...
        return new MyObject();
    }
}

@Data
public class MyModel {
    String area,
    String subArea,
    LocalDate datestamp,
    String leadName,
    String viceLeadName
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that post and it's only binding the path variables. While I'm looking to bind both path variable and request params into 1 single object.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Can you share on how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a Model MyModel

```
  class MyModel {
    String area;
    String subarea;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    LocalDate datestamp;
    String leadname;
    String viceleadname;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyModel [area=" + area + ", subarea=" + subarea + ", datestamp=" + datestamp + ", leadname=" + leadname
                + ", viceneadname=" + viceleadname + "]";
    }
    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }
    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
    public String getSubarea() {
        return subarea;
    }
    public void setSubarea(String subarea) {
        this.subarea = subarea;
    }
    public LocalDate getDatestamp() {
        return datestamp;
    }
    public void setDatestamp(LocalDate datestamp) {
        this.datestamp = datestamp;
    }
    public String getLeadname() {
        return leadname;
    }
    public void setLeadname(String leadname) {
        this.leadname = leadname;
    }
    public String getViceneadname() {
        return viceleadname;
    }
    public void setViceneadname(String viceleadname) {
        this.viceleadname = viceleadname;
    }
```

And the Request mapping will be same as you mentioned.

```
  @GetMapping("/{area}/{subarea}")
    public String getFlight(MyModel model) {
      System.out.println(model);

        return "success";
    }
```

And the Request look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/us/ny?datestamp=2019-05-01&leadname=abc&viceleadname=xyz
```

Comment: this will results MyModel attributes to be null.

Comment: Checked working fine.

Comment: @user29365 what is your request url?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/us/ny?datestamp=2019-05-01&leadname=abc&viceleadname=xyz same hit via postman

Comment: Request url: http://localhost:8080/schedules
```http://localhost:8080/schedules/us/ny?datestamp=2019-05-01&leadname=abc&viceleadname=xyz```

Comment: @user293655  the spellings of attributes of MyModel in the answer is slight difference have updated in your code?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with MyModel.
I'm using Lombok and when I just use a normal getter and setter your answer is working. Maybe I need something extra that can work with lombok?

Comment: Already did accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Location {

    private String area;
    private String subarea;

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getSubarea() {
        return subarea;
    }

    public void setSubarea(String subarea) {
        this.subarea = subarea;
    }

}





@Controller
@RequestMapping("schedules")
public class SchedulesController {

    @GetMapping("{area}/{subarea}")

    public String getFlight(Location location ) {
        String msg = String.format("location request. area: %s, subarea: %s",
                location.getArea(), location.getSubarea());


        ..............................

        return new MyObject();

    }
}
```

do like this way. it will work.

Comment: What about the request params?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/schedules/Bangladesh/Dhaka

Comment: lombok  1.18.6 also work