# Spring Bind @PathVariable to JavaBean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I try to bind an object in Spring controller so it can be used as `@PathVariable`. I want to do so, since there are some `@PathVariable` that I want to pass. I have tried the solution from [Bind Path variables to a custom model object in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149425/bind-path-variables-to-a-custom-model-object-in-spring) and also [Is it possible to bind path variable and request param into a single object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792555/is-it-possible-to-bind-path-variable-and-request-param-into-a-single-object). But both are not working.

I have created something like this in my controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/buildings")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BuildingController {

    private final BuildingService buildingService;

    @GetMapping("/{buildingId}/floors/{floorId}/rooms/{roomId}/sections")
    public Flux<SectionDTO> getRoomSections(BuildingRequestBean request) {
        return this.buildingService.getRoomSections(request);
    }
}
```

and `BuildingRequestBean.java` like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BuildingRequestBean {

  private String buildingId;

  private String floorId;

  private String roomId;
}
```

When I check `BuildingRequestBean`, the attributes is null when I call it with `GET localhost:8080/buildings/a/floors/b/rooms/c/sections`.
However, it will not null if I call it as `@RequestParam`, something like this `GET localhost:8080/buildings/{buildingId}/floors/{floorId}/rooms/{roomId}/sections?buildingId=a&floorId=b&roomId=c`

How to fix it so it will behave like `@PathVariable` rather than behave like `@RequestParam`?

Comment: I am getting same problem and I am using 2.3.2.RELEASE. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: no, i have not found any solution for this

Comment: Yeah probably there is no way in the current spring release. I am manually binding variables and then calling validation through code

Answer (score 0):

U can get it by using `@ModelAttribute`

Try with this:

```
@GetMapping("/{buildingId}/floors/{floorId}/rooms/{roomId}/sections")
    public Flux<SectionDTO> getRoomSections(@ModelAttribute BuildingRequestBean request) {
        return this.buildingService.getRoomSections(request);
    }
```

Comment: I try adding `@ModelAttribute`, however it is not working

Comment: u use spring-boot or spring?

Comment: I use spring-boot 2.2, but it is not working. still act like `@RequestParam`

Comment: if you call this url `localhost:8080/buildings/a/floors/b/rooms/c/sections`. mapping should be work. i tested locally

Answer (score -1):

PathVariable must be added to the function parameter

Try this :

```
@GetMapping("/{buildingId}/floors/{floorId}/rooms/{roomId}/sections")
public Flux<SectionDTO> getRoomSections(@PathVariable String buildingId,@PathVariable String floorId ,@PathVariable String roomId) {
```

Comment: if `@PathVariable` is too many, it will cause the controller become messy. I want the `@PathVariable` can be wrapped in one object.

Comment: with json request {buildingId: x, floorId: y, roomId: z}

@getmapping ( "/FunctionName")
public Flux <SectionDTO> getRoomSections (@RequestBody BuildingRequestBean buildingRequestBean) {

You can use it this way without adding it to the path.